# How to insert extra values in many-to-many table with Objection.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, objection.js

I have the following tables

```
foo     foo_bar    bar
---     -------    ---
id      foo_id     id
        bar_id     data
        num
        desc

foo  bar
---  ---
1    (to be inserted)
2
```

I want to insert data into `bar` linking the inserted entry to an existing element on `foo` table with a many-to-many relationship table `foo_bar`.

Apparently I can do that with:

```
await Bar.query()
  .allowInsert('[foo]')
  .upsertGraph({ data: 'todo', [{ id: 1 }]}, { relate: true });
```

My `Bar` model has

```
static get relationMappings() {
  return {
    foo: {
      join: {
        extra: ['num', 'desc'],
        from: 'bar.id',
        through: {
          from: 'foo_bar.bar_id',
          to: 'foo_bar.foo_id',
        },
        to: 'foo.id',
      },
      modelClass: Foo,
      relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
    },
  };
}
```

But how to I insert values in `num` and `desc` of `foo_bar`? How do I insert values in that middle table?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: 
extra property: Columns listed here are automatically joined to the related objects when they are fetched and automatically written to the join table instead of the related table on insert.

You mentioned the extra property in your model with num and desc columns, so you can put them directly in the upsertGraph like this:

`await Bar.query()
  .allowInsert('[foo]')
  .upsertGraph({ data: 'todo', num: 3, desc: 'bla', [{ id: 1 }]}, { relate: true });`